How to sync the data between all of my apps that use auth0 (universal login)
My Techstack : TALL (tailwind, Alpine.js, Laravel, Livewire)
HI
i am using auth0 universal login and i have multiple app the uses the same auth0 so user can login in all of my apps using one emails in order to save some of the user data in my database i follow this guide provided by auth0
https://github.com/auth0/laravel-auth0/blob/main/docs/Eloquent.md
i let me save some of the data in my database
PROBLEM
The Problem i am have is when i update the using auth0 management api i get update on auth0 server but i does not update on my app unless i  logout and login back the workaround that auth0 suggest is slient login but that only works for the current app and in all the other app i still have the old data i need logout and login back in order to get the new sync data
is there a better way so when update the data using management api i send some kind api request to all my apps so i can sync that data
i am using auth0 and i thought i would sync the data automatically but it seems it does not and i don't how to send a hook or request to all my apps so i can synce the data my self
